# Why can't I change the title of a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to add a title to a UIBarButtonItem. I declared the button as such in the `.h`:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *priceItem;
```

This is the code I currently have in the `viewDidLoad` (it isn't working):

```
NSString *priceOfItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"125.99"];
_priceItem.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", priceOfItem];
```

The idea is that once the view loads, I download a set of instructions from the server and parse the price into a `NSString`, but that isn't the problem. I've setup the `UIToolbar` and `UIBarButtonItem` in Storyboards and have "connected the dots". Xcode is tripping up on the `.text`, saying that `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't have the property `text`. How could this be fixed?

Comment: I believe you want to set the `title` property. `UIBarButtonItem` does not have a `text` property.

Comment: @hw731 Just figured that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

BarButtonItem has the title property. There is no text property.

```
 NSString *priceOfItem = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",@"125.99"];
_priceItem.title = priceOfItem;
```

Comment: Why does the code use two calls to `stringWithFormat:`? One is enough for this job.

Comment: Agree. Updated the change

Comment: While better, there is still no need for a formatted string. Just use `_priceItem.title = @"$125.99";` But then again, I imagine the `125.99` isn't really hardcoded. @James - you really should use an `NSNumberFormatter` for format numbers for user display.